# Is there a way to curve text/labels in Cocos2d?

Tags: ios, text, cocos2d-iphone, label

[Here is an example](http://spiralforums.biz/uploads/monthly_11_2011/post-19351-0-33892000-1320165402.jpg) of what I would like to achieve.

**Is there a way to "transform" a label in Cocos2d and obtain a curved text?** I do not find any property in the CCLabelBMFont class that seem to allow this.

Any suggestion wellcome.

Rason for asking: I would prefer not to use pre-generated (with Photoshop or GIMP) text images. Hence I am looking for an answer to this problem and not to an alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

One of the moderators of the Cocos2D forum has [replied](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/is-there-a-way-to-curve-textlabels-in-cocos2d/#post-408032) to me in their forum and it doesn't seem possible. Here is the link to the discussion on the forum, but as far as I can tell there is no solution (In my opinion it would require having implemented a draw call in the labels that blends the pixtures according to the new image matrix resulting from bending the original label image and as far as I can understand CCLabelBMFont does not seem to support this - and I am not sure that is easily possible to do so as the class does not derive from CCSprite but it may be in some other way that I do not know at the moment).